# CA signed certificate failed to verify

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, certificate, curl

I have a signed CA certificate which I installed on my Apache webserver. The certificate is valid and is signed by internal CA. 
I spun another Linux instance and tried curling the address but I am not sure why curl is complaining about legitimacy of the server.

```
curl https://website.local
curl: (60) SSL Certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could nt establish a secure connection to it.
```

i was using a self signed certificate before that I generated using openssl. I was getting the same message but that made sense. This doesn't as the certificate is signed and I checked the entire certificate chain and it appears to be valid.

Please can someone help me understand, where am I wrong?

PS: The CA signed certificate is NOT installed on any other instances. The only certificate installed is on the Apache webserver.

I got an internal CA certificate now and I installed that and now I am getting a something different. This message is from an instance which doesn't have CA certificate installed and is curling the address of an instance which has the CA certificate installed.

```
curl performs SSL certificates verification by default, using a "bundle" of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs)> If the default bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file using the --cacert option.
```

There's more to the message I guess subject experts will know what follows. Why is it throwing error when there is an internal CA certificate installed?

Comment: Is the certificate signed by the self-signed CA certificate, installed on all machines and servers, the CA certificate should also be installed on all machines.  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: If there is more to a message include it.